# Passing of json request in load runner multiple times with modified json

Tags: loadrunner

I have the request where I need to send the parameters as JSON objects to update the time for different rounds. I am having some difficulty doing that. Below is my request. I have replaced each of the start and end times with the current date and next day date using the lr_save_datetime. The issue now is there are now 8 objects in the JSON request. When it is the 1st round we send all the 8 objects in the JSON request when it is the 2nd round we need to send only 7 objects from the JSON request(excluding the first object from the previous JSON request). I appreciate any help on how to do this.

```
web_custom_request("Edit-Time", 
    "URL=https://some.com/EditTime", 
    "Method=PUT", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/vnd.api+json", 
    "Referer=https://some.com/edit", 
    "Snapshot=t27.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    "Body={\"data\":[{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"2019-10-21T16:20:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"{Curr_Date}T{New_Time}.000-0400\",\"fixed-start\":true,\"visible\":true},\"relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"1\"},{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"{New_Date}T13:50:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"{New_Date}T14:50:00.000-0400\",\"fixed-start\":false,\"visible\":true},\"relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\""
    ":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"2\"},{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"{New_Date}T15:50:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"{New_Date}T16:50:00.000-0400\",\"fixed-start\":false,\"visible\":true},\"relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"3\"},{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"{New_Date}T17:50:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"{New_Date}T18:50:00.000-0400\",\"fixed-start\":false,\"visible\":true},\"relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{"
    "\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"4\"},{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"{New_Date}T19:50:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"{New_Date}T20:50:00.000-0400\",\"fixed-start\":false,\"visible\":false},\"relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"5\"},{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"{New_Date}T21:50:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"{New_Date}T22:50:00.000-0400\",\"fixed-start\":false,\"visible\":false},\""
    "relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"6\"},{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"{New_Date}T23:50:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"2019-11-26T08:50:00.000-0400\",\"fixed-start\":false,\"visible\":false},\"relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"7\"},{\"attributes\":{\"starts-at\":\"2019-10-26T09:50:00.000-0400\",\"ends-at\":\"2019-10-26T10:50:00.000-0400\",\""
    "fixed-start\":false,\"visible\":false},\"relationships\":{\"schedule\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"schedules\",\"id\":\"1\"}}},\"type\":\"rounds\",\"id\":\"8\"}]}", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=schedule", "Referer=https://some.com/edit", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a good way of doing that without writing some C code. I am still not sure why you are using Web HTTP/HTML protocol and not TruWeb protocol.